# I need filter dozen of pdf files in folder by some word

Tags: python, filter

hello everyone I need help writing code about filtering pdf files in one folder

that folder contains dozens of pdf files I need to filter the file by searching every text line from all files about some words.

then I want to move the file that contains that word to other files

please help me out or at least want some sources to write this code

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

you can use `glob()` to filter the extension of file in our case it is pdf from the directory and after that can filter the files with name you want by using `contains()` in a string.

```
import glob, os

folder_path = '/Downloads'

os.chdir(folder_path)
files = [file for file in glob.glob("*.pdf")]
files = [file for file in files if file.__contains__('xyz')]
print(files)
```

Comment: kindly want more details could you please tell me step by step from open python till the end

Comment: Hi zaid, I have updated the code and you can use it according to your code structure

Comment: Pleasure! please consider upvoting / checkmarking answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs a tool for this, please take a look at https://github.com/ddomnik/PDFFilter. There you can also find the source code useful for your own project.